# Why does ConvertAPI not working using PHP library

Tags: php, converters

I am using ConvertAPI using PHP Library [ConvertAPI]

Yesterday My code is Working proper of ConvertAPI .But Suddenly Today It's not working and Give me error **Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received**. I have not change of single line of code.But I don't know Why its give an error.please help me someone who know the issue.

My code are below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP - Convert API Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Add Image:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
     </form>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>

<?php 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \ConvertApi\ConvertApi;

ConvertApi::setApiSecret('My-secret-key');

if(!empty($_FILES["file"])){
   try {
    if(count($_FILES['file']['name']) > 0){

       $newFileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
       //Loop through each file
       for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
       //Get the temp file path
          $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
          $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
          $newFileName = substr($fileName, 0 , (strrpos($fileName, ".")));      
         //Make sure we have a filepath
          if($tmpFilePath != ""){   

              //save the filename
              $shortname = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
              //save the url and the file
              $filePath = "uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
              //Upload the file into the temp dir
              if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {
                 $files[] = $shortname;               
              }
              $result = ConvertApi::convert('jpg', ['File' => $filePath]);
              $final_result = $result->response['Files'][0]['FileName'];
            //echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
             $result->getFile()->save('uploads/'.$newFileName.'.jpg');        
           }
     }
  }

}
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Something else went wrong: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
}
```

For this I installed PHP Library using

**composer require convertapi/convertapi-php**

Comment: `Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds`. Maybe the API endpoint is currently offline / down. You could ask the support: https://www.convertapi.com/support

Comment: I got the solution . My free second is used . So, it gives error like this.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me on linux.
edit the file:

```
sudo /etc/resolv.conf
```

and paste the following:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

OpenDNS will be used, comment out the existing nameserves in the file